# SQL Server Management Studio using While loop function to split result

Tags: sql-server

I have a task to find a way to use `WHILE` loop function to try to split a single selected result into many, the table is simple column in (var) format looks like :

```
SELECT [Names ID] 
FROM [Names Database]
```

The result is just a column with numbers some of which are repeated many times. My question is there a way to use `WHILE` function to split the result grouped by those `[Names ID]` numbers so it looks like I used `SELECT` and `WHERE` filter for each different number?

i used this :

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID) as [number]
INTO [ID NUMBERS]
FROM [Customer]

USE [TEST];
GO
DECLARE @N int = 0
WHILE (SELECT max(NUMBER) FROM [ID NUMBERS] ) > @N 
BEGIN
SET @N = @N + 1
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,number FROM [ID NUMBERS]
END
```

i used the dense_rank basically not to calculate the long customer_id +1 the result i get looks like :

[image]

how can i fix it too look like this :

[image]

manage to get the result i want by using this :

SELECT distinct CUSTOMER_ID
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID) as [number] INTO [TEST].[Trainee].[ID NUMBERS] FROM [TEST]  USE [TEST]; GO DECLARE @N BIG INT = 1  WHILE (SELECT max(NUMBER) FROM [TEST][ID NUMBERS] ) >= @N  BEGIN
          SELECT  @N
             ,ID.[Customer_ID]
             ,[number]
         FROM [TEST].[ID NUMBERS] AS ID
        WHERE @N = NUMBER    SET @N = @N + 1 END

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are asking for.  Can you post data sample and expected result?

Comment: I hope that helps. No idea what to do.

Comment: What is the difficulty here?   WHILE is pretty simple.   What did you try?

Comment: Using a while loop to split strings is sort of like taking a gremlin to the Indy 500. Sure it might finish the race but it will be miles behind the competitors. Don't do this with a loop, it is horrible. If you absolutely have to split strings (storing data properly is much better alternative) then look here for some far better ideas than loops. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: @Ace you say `split` but your question doesn't deal with strings at all. What are you trying to do? Do you really want to return 3 different result sets?

Comment: i manage to get the result that i want by following what Tab_alleman suggested . Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0):

You can do a WHILE loop from the MIN value of the table to the MAX value, increasing it by one each time, and doing an `IF EXISTS(...) SELECT...` inside the loop.

EDIT based on edit to question:

I don't know what made you think you could use DENSE_RANK as a shortcut.  You can't.

Start with `@N` as the MIN `Customer_ID`.

in the loop, SELECT the rows where `Customer_ID=@N`.   Be sure to use IF EXISTS() so you don't get empty result sets for non-existing customer numbers.

Loop WHILE `@N` is less than or equal to the MAX `Customer_ID`.

Comment: Thank you i was trying something similar but had some problems since those are just example numbers the real ones are in varchar and are like 8 digit long.

Comment: That's fine, it shouldn't matter how long the ID's are, though you may have to use a `BIGINT` instead of an `INT` for the WHILE loop counter.

Comment: Tab , would you please check my updated code and the results and how can i fix it :) ?